# Regex Search-and-Replace with Capture Groups?

Tags: apex, string, regular-expressions

In IDEs a common operation is to perform a search and replace operation using a regex pattern in the search field and another pattern with capture groups in the replacement field.

For example, I can search for `(\d)(\D)(\d)` and replace it with `first: \1; second: \2; third: \3`. This would produce the following results.

- "1a2" => "first: 1; second: a; third: 2"
- "8o8" => "first: 8; second: o; third: 8"

Is there an easy way to perform this same operation on a [String](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) object in Apex? I'm looking for a solution that isn't hard-constrained to only process three capture groups. The number of capture groups is variable: could be 2, 3, 5 or any number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [Matcher](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm) and [Pattern](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_pattern_methods.htm#apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_pattern_methods) classes, that can be used to use regex.
for example the following code does, that you want

```
String toCheck = '1a2';
Map<Integer, String> descriptionToGroupNumber = new Map<Integer, String>{
    1 => 'first',
    2 => 'second',
    3 => 'third',
    4 => 'fourth',
    5 => 'fifth'
};
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile('(\\d)(\\D)(\\d)');
Matcher match = pat.matcher(toCheck);
Integer groupsToCapture = match.groupCount();
while(match.find()){
    String output = '';
    for(Integer i = 1; i <= groupsToCapture; i++){
        if(i != 1){
           output +=' '; 
        }
        output +=descriptionToGroupNumber.get(i)+': '+ match.group(i);
        if(i != groupsToCapture){
           output+=';';
        }
    }
    System.debug(output);  
}
```

output is

> DEBUG|first: 1; second: a; third: 2

`\1` equals to capturing specific group `match.group(1)`

Comment: Thanks for the first answer, Alex. I'm looking for a solution that isn't hard-constrained to only process three capture groups. The number of capture groups is variable: could be 2, 3, 5 or any number.

Comment: Thank you also for pointing out the unclear requirement in my question. I've edited the question to explain that I'm seeking a dynamic solution.

Comment: @MartyC. I've updated my answer with case, when there could be unknown number of groups

Answer (score 4):

You can use `$#` to reference a capture group (`$1` is the first, `$2` is the second, etc.)

For your case I ran this:

```
System.debug('1a2'.replaceAll('(\\d)(\\D)(\\d)', 'first: $1; second: $2, third: $3'));
System.debug('8o8'.replaceAll('(\\d)(\\D)(\\d)', 'first: $1; second: $2, third: $3'));
```

And got this:

```
first: 1; second: a, third: 2
first: 8; second: o, third: 8
```